# Ruby/Rspec assert that first 4 characters match given text

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a timestamp

```
timestamp = 1466754627
```

And I want to assert that the first 4 characters are `1466` within a test. If i was to use

```
timestamp.includes('1466')
```

This will pass, but `1466` could appear anywhere and not necessarily the first 4 characters. How could i ensure that `1466` are the first 4 characters ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [`start_with` matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-4/docs/built-in-matchers/start-with-matcher):

```
expect('1466754627').to start_with('1466')
```

You might have to convert `timestamp` to a string via [`to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) if it is indeed an integer:

```
timestamp = 1466754627
expect(timestamp.to_s).to start_with('1466')
```

Comment: @Richlewis chances are that your test will fail in about 4 days ;-)

Comment: oh yes you're right, best stick with checking the length then, gives me until 2038 then :-)